# Using "this"/"super" in the subclass both give superclass's fields but only "super" is allowed in subclass constructor

Tags: java, constructor, this, super

I'm trying to understand the usage of this and super in subclass methods and in subclass constructor:

super class:

```
public class Animal {
    protected String name;
    protected String age;

    public Animal(String name, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

this and super keywords used in the subclass method:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {

    public Dog(String name, String age) {
        super(name, age);
    }

    public void display() {
        this.name = "Doggy";
        super.age = "20";
        System.out.println(this.name + " is " + super.age + " years old");
    }
}
```

What is the difference between "this" and "super" in the above case? And why is it that in the subclass constructor we can't use "this" to initialize the fields inherited from the superclass, as in the below case, but we can use super() to initialize the same fields in the superclass?

```
public class Dog extends Animal {

    public Dog(String name, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: FWIW, in your 'display' method, you don't need `this` or `super` at all. Their role in that context is to explicitly specify which object you are talking about (and there is only one object there, despite it being defined by two class definitions).

Comment: "*What is the difference between "this" and "super" in the above case?*" in your case there is no difference because you did not redefine fields with *same names* in your subclass. "*And why is it that in the subclass constructor we can't use "this" to initialize the fields inherited from the superclass*" we can but this is not the problem. Issue here is that first instruction in constructor needs to be call to some `super(..)`. It can be left if you wish compiler to generate `super()` but since your superclass doesn't have no-argument constructor you need to call it explicitly.

Comment: Tldr, please "study" https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.2 (Ctrl+f, "this", "super")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this`, the keyword, has two separate jobs.

It's exactly like how `+` means two **completely** different things in java: `5 + 2` does integer addition, `"foo" + "bar"` does string concatenation. Same symbol, 2 unrelated jobs. In english, The word **bank** means both the land next to a river and also a financial institution. Same word, 2 unrelated jobs.

`this` is no different.

1. It means 'this object'. There is only one object here: An object of type Dog. There isn't 'a Dog object' and contained inside it a separate 'Animal super object'. That's not how it works. There is just the Dog object, which contains all fields - any fields you defined in Dog, and any field you defined in Animal.

Hence, `this.someFieldDefinedInYourSuperClass = foo;` is fine, and that makes sense.

2. It also means: Select a constructor. This version of the `this` keyword always comes with parentheses immediately following the keyword. `this(params);` is what it looks like, and it lets you invoke one of your constructors from another one of your constructors. `super()` is a similar construct that lets you call one of your super constructors. Note that all constructors must neccessarily use one of these; if you fail to do so the compiler injects `super();` as first line in your constructor silently.

Example:

```
public Student(LocalDate birthDate, String name) {
  this(generateNewStudentId(), birthDate, name);
}

public Student(String id, LocalDate birthDate, String name) {
  this.id = id;
  this.birthDate = birthDate;
  this.name = name;
}
```

here the first usage is simply: Call the other constructor using the provided values. The second (and third and fourth) usages are the 'it is this object' variant.

In your example, you use `super(name, age);`. This invokes the `public Animal(String name, int age)` constructor from your superclass. It doesn't "set the name and the age" - it calls that constructor. What that constructor does? Who knows - you'd have to check the source. Maybe the constructor plays Feliz Navidad from the speakers first. You happen to know that it 'just' does `this.name = name; this.age = age;` but that's just because that's what's currently in `Animal.java`.

In contrast, `this.name = name;` means "set the value of this object's `name` field to the  value of the `name` parameter".

Comment: thanks rzwitserloot, very clear!

Answer (score 2):

In `display()` the `this.` and `super.` are not needed. They would only be needed if the child class declared member variables with the same names as the super class:

```
public static class Animal {
    protected String name;
    protected String age;

    public Animal(String name, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
public static class Dog extends Animal {

    protected String name;   // These are different from the ones
    protected String age;    // in Animal

    public Dog(String name, String age) {
        super(name, age);
        this.name = "Something else";
        this.age = "123";
    }

    public void display() {
        super.name = "Doggy";  // Need super. to differentiate from Dog class's name
        this.age = "20";
        System.out.println(this.name + " is " + this.age + " years old");
        System.out.println(super.name + " is " + super.age + " years old");
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Dog dog = new Dog("Sparky", "3");
    dog.display();
}
```

Output is:

```
Something else is 20 years old
Doggy is 3 years old
```

Answer (score 1):

With `this` -> you are pointing to the current object, to be more precise to the object that will be created from the current class. With the `super` you are able to access the fields from the parent class in this case `Animal`. To be more precise, YES you are able with `super` to access the `age` parameter since it's defined in the `Animal` (the parent class) but all fields that are going to be defined in `Dog` should be pointed with `this`. Also notice that in the constructor of `Dog` you must call `super` because you defined constructor in `Animal` saying that those fields will be set on creation of the object and again in `Dog` you are giving them values.